# Transferring Chrome profile from broken computer to new one to recover saved passwords

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-registry

so my computer broke last week and I can't even get into the BIOS, so I took the hard drive out, plugged it into a sata to usb adapter and I have managed to recover my files. There is one problem... I need my chrome passwords that I saved, so I decided to copy over the "User Data" folder from Chrome, and it did everything I needed EXCEPT for copying over the password.

After awhile of looking, I found out I need to copy over a registry key called "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs]" problem is, I can't actually access that specific registry, as HKEY_CURRENT_USER is for the currently logged in user.
Is there any way I can get "PreferenceMACs" from my currently removed hard drive so I can completely transfer chrome profiles? If there is another way of recovering my chrome passwords though, I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may load the registry hive of the user from the hard disk:

- Run `regedit`
- Use menu *File > Load Hive*
- Select the user's hive at: `X:\Users\USER-NAME\NTUSER.DAT`
- Give it any name you like
- A new node with this name will appear under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
- Export or copy from the new node any data that you require
- When finished, select the node and do *File > Unload Hive*.